# Objective-C Photo Upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

`FBDialogs` function to present dialogs with photos always returns `No`.

I can't understand why...

Here is code:

```
UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageInfo objectAtIndex:1]];





BOOL canPresent = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos];
NSLog(@"canPresent: %d", canPresent);

FBPhotoParams *params = [[FBPhotoParams alloc] init];
params.photos = @[image2];

BOOL isSuccessful = NO;
if (canPresent) {
    FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                                                          clientState:nil
                                                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                                  if (error) {
                                                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                                  } else {
                                                                      NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                                  }
                                                              }];
    isSuccessful = (appCall  != nil);
}
```

Comment: Is that code using the FaceBook Messenger.app? Is this app allowed to access photos?

Comment: Does your app should then open FaceBook Messenger.app? If yes does FaceBook Messenger.app allowed to access Photos.app ?

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have? Are you doing this on a simulator or a device?

Comment: I download facebook sdk 3.15.1 , I'm doing on simulator .

Comment: I download facebook sdk 3.15.1 , I'm doing on simulator .